# three and condition in sql statement in Yii

Tags: mysql, sql, database, yii, controller

I have three and conditions but the result is coming empty although when I run the query on localserver with simple sql it works fine but in yii sql query it does not give me the proper result, i rubbed one '`andwhere`' condition and it works fine, but i want to run it with two '`andwhere`' conditions.

The query which i run on local server with simple sql is

```
SELECT business_id,isdeleted,user_id FROM `review_business` where user_id=13 and isdeleted is NULL and business_id=91
```

and the query which i am trying to run in yii is

```
$results = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('r.user_id,r.business_id,r.isdeleted')
                ->from('review_business r')
                ->where('r.user_id=' . $u_id)
                ->andWhere('r.isdeleted=Null')
                ->andWhere('r.business_id=' . $bid)
                ->queryALL();
```

Comment: Just as a test, does it work if you hardcode the values? like `->where('r.user_id=13')` and `->andWhere('r.business_id=91')`

Comment: how about the case sensitive of queryAll()?

Answer (score 0):

Use "IS NULL" instead of "=NULL" in your first andWhere condition.